# Error during installation pdf generator extension via ssh

Tags: magento-2.1, module, extensions

I am trying to install a `pdf generator extension` but Iihave an error ``(via composer)` from here: [Github](https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2)

I run below command:

```
>composer require eadesignro/module-pdfgenerator
```

then ask me about token then I generated the github token and typed.  I received the information that the token is correct and then the error:

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone git@github.com:EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2.git, git wa
  s not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.

  sh: git: command not found
```

anyone know how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have to install **git** first.
If you are on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```